# Задать параметр в метод jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пользуюсь "кроппером" https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper

Выбираю изображение для cropper:

```
var image = $('#cropper > img');
```

Получаю данные по умолчанию из скрытого input'a:

```
var cropData = $("#params").val();
```

Инициализирую сам cropper:

```
    image.cropper({
        aspectRatio: 1,
        autoCropArea: 0.65,
        zoomable: false,
        minCropBoxWidth: 50,
        minCropBoxHeight: 50,
        data: cropData,
    });
```

Параметр *data* не получает данные из *cropData*, если же указать что-то вроде:

```
data: {"x":420.84485791610285,"y":100.70209742895806,"width":349.70000000000005,"height":349.70000000000005,"rotate":0},
```

То все работает.

Вывод:

```
console.log(cropData)

{"x":420.84485791610285,"y":100.70209742895806,"width":349.70000000000005,"height":349.70000000000005,"rotate":0},
```

Помогите правильно задать параметр... В *JS* и *jQuery* ни разу не силен.
Спасибо.

Comment: В данные из инпут получает cropData. <input id="params" name="cropper_coords" type="hidden" value="{&quot;x&quot;:205.29905277401895,&quot;y&quot;:50.232746955345064,&quot;width&quot;:401.8619756427605,&quot;height&quot;:401.8619756427605,&quot;rotate&quot;:0}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вероятно, `$("#params").val()` возвращает строку, а вам нужен объект. Решается просто: `var cropDataJSON = JSON.parse(cropData);`
2. Запятая меня слегка смущает, не должно оно работать с лишней запятой в конце:

   ```
     image.cropper({
       aspectRatio: 1,
       autoCropArea: 0.65,
       zoomable: false,
       minCropBoxWidth: 50,
       minCropBoxHeight: 50,
       // вот так было
       // data: cropData,
       // вот так надо:
       data: cropData
     });
   ```

Comment: Спасибо! так работает. С запятой и без работает! Запятой нет на самом деле, там еще параметры идут)

Comment: Нажмите галочку под рейтингом ответа, чтобы отметить его как верный. Спасибо.

Comment: Современные броузеры запятую сами подчищают (Chrome, IE11), а старые - нет. Проверил в IE9 - код валится с ошибкой `Expected identifier, string or number`

Comment: Спасибо за ценный комментарий. На самом деле там еще ряд параметров перечислен которые я не стал копировать, а при копипасте сюда просто забыл удалить запятую.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, насколько я знаю и из старых браузеров только IE и не подчищает. И мне казалось что IE9 должен уже такую конструкцию проглатываеть если не выставлен quirks mode конечно. Вот IE8- точно падают.

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, уточнил, IE8-9 "принципиально" работают с висячими запятыми в объектах, но в некоторых минорных релизах эта функциональность поломана. С висячими запятыми в массивах корректно работают I9+ (вероятно за исключением тех же минорных релизов)

Comment: @MakarovAV Зря, кстати, по-моему, подчищают :) Если типизация нестрогая - так хоть за синтаксисом бы более-менее строго следили... А уж в HTML - так вообще страшные вещи творят. В стиле `<select><option>xxx<option><option>yyy<option></select>` из недавнего вопроса.

Comment: Для перфекционистов есть use strict или как там =)

Comment: @Regent, так емнип по стандарту подчищать надо, стандарт - наше все) Хотя мне конечно тоже такое поведение не нравится, но наверняка у разработчиков стандарта были свои причины

Comment: @SergeySnegirev, use strict поведение висячих запятых не меняет, роль "или как там" выполняет JSLint